# Xcode iOS password get AF 'posted' with "some" hash / type of encryption - what kind?

Tags: post, alamofire, swift4, xcode9, sha256

I'm testing an app not yet published. I have a client side register/log-in, using Alamofire to post and then retrieve and parse JSON. Unless Alamofire has "blackboxed" some type of hash, I am not aware of having coded any kind of hash anywhere, yet.

When I went to look into why the test passwords (passed via SSL, HTTPS, and without any effort to encrypt, yet) were showing up on the server side looking like the result of a hash, I compared that result to a deliberate server side Sha256 hash (done on the raw, plain text password matching the original that got passed from the app). I am seeing this:

```
"ccc" ---->  Sha256 hash = 64daa44ad493ff28a96effab6e77f1732a3d97d83241581b37dbd70a7a4900fe
"ccc" ----> "simple iOS post" (via Alamofire) = 9df62e693988eb4e1e1444ece0578579
```

As you can see, the values are very different, and this means unless I know what happened on the way over, I cannot authenticate anyone on the server side, nor can I use any server side password reset functions, because I have no idea what kind of hash was used.

Can anyone help me know what happened to hash the password?

Here's the simple Alamofire-based code doing the post (Xcode 9, Swift 4):

```
//creating parameters for the post request
let parameters: Parameters=[
    "username":textFieldUserName.text!,
    "password":textFieldPassword.text!,
    "name":textFieldName.text!,
    "email":textFieldEmail.text!,
    "phone":textFieldPhone.text!,
    "user_type":String(user_type),
    "user_privileges":String(user_privileges)
]

print("Post Contents ('parameters') = \(parameters)")

//Sending http post request
Alamofire.request(URL_USER_REGISTER, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
    {
        response in
        //printing response
        print(response)

        //getting the json value from the server
        if let result = response.result.value {

            //converting it as NSDictionary
            let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I feel sheepish. I found a hash being applied in the PHP on the server side.

```
md5($pass);
```

No need to bother with this one. Now wish I had not even posted it. But, maybe it will help someone.

Comment: Also forgive me having made the common mistake of confusing hash with encryption. I know they are not the same (the former is undoable, the latter is, and would be wasted if it were undoable).